# Error while Installing Debian on a KVM --> apt configuration problem

Tags: debian, apt, debian-installer, apt-mirror

currently I'm trying to install Debian 10 (newest version) on my freshly rested VM. I'm getting no errors, until the installer tries to Configure the package manager. Then I get the error, that "the attempt to configure apt to install additional packages from the CD failed." [image: error]
When I ignore that, and enter my mirror country and so, when the installer is trying to configure apt, it  says that there's a "Bad archive mirror". [image: error 2 here]

So, what can I do? Any Ideas? I'm happy about everything :)

Comment: I would start by checking whether your network is working. Presumably you are trying to configure an ethernet card? I'd get a minimal installation going first, and check whether the network has been properly configured before proceeding.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I had already installed ubuntu and the installation worked just fine. Should I try install a Live OS and ping something or so?

Comment: Sure, you could try that. But in any case it sounds like your apt config problem is actually a network problem. You could also do a separate regular installion of Debian and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Faheem Mitha](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4671/faheem-mitha) has suggested, it was a network issue. My Hoster just didn't had a DHCP-server, so I had to enter my network details via the Debian expert install manually.

Thanks to [Faheem Mitha](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4671/faheem-mitha)!